# Compare and select data in two different CSV files in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I attached an image. I have two different CSV file and want to get output as shown in an attached file. Below is the  sample input and  output I want

[image]

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on what you want to do.  Please provide a desired output example.

Comment: Thank you. Sure, let say I have two CSV files as I attached (Both have columns a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i and a similar column called the origin.). The outcome would be, if "a" value for origin 251720 is above 1 in csv 1 is and if "a" value for origin 251720 is less than 1 then show me 251720.

Comment: @Rexovas Thank you. Sure, let say I have two CSV files as I attached (Both have columns a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i and a similar column called the origin.). The outcome would be, if "a" value for origin 251720 is above 1 in csv 1 is and if "a" value for origin 251720 is less than 1 then show me 251720.

Comment: if "a" is greater than 1 in file1, return the origin value? Or return the origin only if "a" in file1 is above 1, AND "a" in file2 is less than 1? What do we return if neither value is less than/greater than 1? Also, do you want to output the results to another csv?  It would be helpful if you could update your post and add another image link illustrating the output.

Comment: @Rexovas return the origin only if "a" in file1 is above 1, AND "a" in file 2 is less than 1. return zero if neither value is less than/greater than 1. It would be great if I get another CSV as an output

Comment: ok, I will update my answer.  Will there always be a value in columns a,b,c... or are there blank cells?

Comment: @Rexovas Thank you very much. it can have blank as well. I updated the post with an image

Comment: Pardon the delay, I had to step out.  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can read both CSV files with Pandas (`pip install pandas`)

```
file1 = pd.read_csv("file1.csv").fillna(0)
file2 = pd.read_csv("file2.csv").fillna(0)
```

If the files consist of the same columns and same number of rows, you can compare several values from a column like this:

```
comparison = [a - b for a, b in zip(file1.loc[:, 'column_name'], file2.loc[:, 'column_name'])]
```

this will result in a list with the difference between a (file1 column value) and b (file2 column value).

You can add the results to a new column in one of your dataframes like such:

```
file1.loc[:, 'new_column'] = comparison
```

In your specific case, we can perform our comparison of each column like so (this assumes the order of your "origins" are the same in both files):

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for column in file1:
     if not column == 'origin':
          df.loc[:, column] = [origin if a < 1 <= b else 0 for origin, a, b in zip(file1.loc[:, 'origin'], file1.loc[:, column], file2.loc[:, column])]
```

using your example this would result in:

```
         a       b       c
0   251720       0       0
1   252530       0       0
2   261900       0       0
3   262110       0       0
4   300692       0  300692
5   380210       0  380210
6   382510       0  382510
7   382530  382530       0
8   382541  382541       0
9   382549  382549       0
10  382550  382550       0
11  382561       0       0
12  382569       0       0
```

you can then export this to a new csv as follows:
`df.to_csv(“output.csv”, index=False)`